# @Override causes issues with class hierarchy involving interface, abstract class and concrete class

Tags: java

My classes are as follows

```
public interface A {
    public void doSomething();
}
public abstract class B implements A {
    public void doOneMoreThing() {
        // Do one more thing
    }
}
public class C extends B {
    @Override                <---- Causes error
    public void doSomething() {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Could somebody tell me, why this @Override annotation is causing error?

Thanks
Nayn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check that you are using JDK 1.6 and that your -source and -target parameters (if defined) set to 1.6.  The semantics of @Override changed in Java 6.
In Java 5, @Override was not allowed to override interface methods (only superclass methods), but it is allowed in Java 6 (and recent versions of JDK 5, from u21 onwards)

See [Why is javac failing on @Override annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335655/why-is-javac-failing-on-override-annotation)

Comment: Precise. I was using 1.5 Thanks.

Comment: Actually, setting source and target to 1.5 won't produce this error. Nor will the latest update release of JDK 1.5.  Only older versions of JDK 1.5.

Comment: Plus, if `-source 1.6 -target 1.6` worked, that would mean he's on JDK 1.6 or later, in which case there would be no reason to specify those arguments, would there?

Comment: @Kevin Bourrillion - I use JDK 6 and often have projects inadvertently set to -source/-target 1.5. (E.g. when importing a maven project into IDEA - my common parent pom defines source to be 1.5.) So, this would be the fix in such a case. I wasn't considering that he was actually using JDK 1.5, and that's not the intent of my post. I think your downvote is harsh considering the the answer solved the OP's problem, and that the answer is valid in the typical case of using 1.6.

Comment: I know there are differing philosophies about downvotes. I tend to believe the concept is more useful when we're not afraid to use it on answers that just aren't very good/useful (as opposed to that the answer has to be BAD).  However, your new edit is a lot better, so good-bye downvote.

Answer (score 2):

you should use

@Override

You wrote @Overrides and then it doesn't work anymore ;)

Comment: I use eclipse and hence did not make any mistake in that. I understand what @Override means.

Comment: then chcek if your using java 1.6. @override for interfaces is only available 1.6 and above