# @Override not accepted as valid in eclipse in private inner class delclarations?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm overriding some classes in eclipse android java project in my local private inner classes and although I see projects where this is handled fine in my particular project settings its complaining Must override a method which is exactly what it is doing????  Thanks

Comment: Please post the code in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[My guess, before code of the op]

In Java 6, you can use @Override to annotate a method that implement an interface. In Java 5 you are not allow to do that.

See: [Why is javac failing on @Override annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335655/why-is-javac-failing-on-override-annotation)

Comment: Thanks for this... I couldn't figure out what the problem was when I switched machines.  1.5 was enabled, switched to 1.6 and everything is great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't override a private method.

Are the supertype's *methods* private, or just the class itself?