# Maven: javac: source release 1.6 requires target release 1.6

Tags: java, maven, javac

NOTE:  This appears to be a limit in the "javac" program.

I have Java 6 code that needs to be built for a Java 5 JVM.  My previous work with the javac ant target (both with the JDK compiler and with ecj) led me to believe that it would simply be a matter of setting source and target for javac.  Hence this pom.xml fragment:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.5</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

which works as expected from within Eclipse 3.7 with Maven support.  Unfortunately, running Maven directly from the command line give me

```
javac: source release 1.6 requires target release 1.6
```

which is the same as generated by `javac -source 1.6 -target 1.5`. To clarify, this is the official OpenJDK 6 for Ubuntu

```
x@JENKINS:~$ javac -version
javac 1.6.0_20
x@JENKINS:~$ javac -source 1.6 -target 1.5
javac: source release 1.6 requires target release 1.6
x@JENKINS:~$
```

The official Oracle Java 7 JDK for Windows show the same behavior.

Note:  I do not want to build against Java 5 libraries or anything.  Just that the active javac generates Java 5 *compatible* bytecode.

How do I get what I want while still being compatible with the Eclipse Maven plugin?

(EDIT: In addition to the @Override I also want to compile against the JAX-WS libraries in Java 6 when used, but still generated Java 5 byte code - I can then add the JAX-WS libraries deliberately in the web container when deploying to a Java 5 installation)

---

EDIT:  It turns out that maven-compiler-plugin can be told to use another compiler, and the Eclipse compiler can do this:

```
        <plugin>
            <!-- Using the eclipse compiler allows for different source and target, 
                which is a good thing (outweighing that this is a rarely used combination, 
                and most people use javac) This should also allow us to run maven builds 
                on a JRE and not a JDK. -->

            <!-- Note that initial experiments with an earlier version of maven-compiler-plugin 
                showed that the eclipse compiler bundled with that gave incorrect lines in 
                the debug information. By using a newer version of the plexus-compiler-eclipse 
                plugin this is hopefully less of an issue. If not we must also bundle a newer 
                version of the eclipse compiler itself. -->

            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
                <debug>true</debug>
                <optimize>false</optimize>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <compilerId>eclipse</compilerId>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>plexus-compiler-eclipse</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

which compiles the class to Java 1.5 bytecode without complaints.  This is also supported "out of the box" for m2e for Eclipse Java EE 4.2.2.

EDIT:  I found that of all things the *javadoc* tool dislikes the output from the Eclipse compiler.

EDIT 2015-06-28:  I did a quick test recently and the latest ecj (corresponding to Eclipse 4.4) worked fine with javadoc.

Comment: I hope this guild will give some hints http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-jdk14-on-jdk15.html

Comment: Note:  Question edited to clarify what I want, and that I still need to be Eclipse compatible.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I'll give you another chance then. how was the javactask configured? According to the docs the source parameter is ignored for most of the compilers: "Value of the -source command-line switch; will be ignored by all implementations prior to javac1.4 (or modern when Ant is not running in a 1.3 VM), gcj and jikes."

Comment: @PeterLiljenberg that is for ant tasks, not maven tasks.  I do not know if compiling "outside" the Maven engine looses any kind of information or reporting back.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The limitation is in javac.  The solution is to tell maven to use another compiler.  See question for details.

Comment: Note:  The javadoc byte code interpreter crashes on byte code generated by the Eclipse compiler.

Comment: This appears to have been fixed in newer versions of the Eclipse compiler.

Answer (score 8):

It seems if you want to do cross compilation you need to supply a couple of extra arguments **-bootclasspath** and **-extdirs**, although I believe you only need the first.  For using Javac and example can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html#crosscomp-example) with an explanation of the additional options [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html#options) (Cross-Compilation Options section).

You would then need to configure these options for your maven-compiler-plugin.  From what I understand you need to set to plugin to fork so that it will use the compiler arguments rather than the built in compiler.  You can find a listing of all the options [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html)

```
 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <bootclasspath>${1.5.0jdk}\lib\rt.jar</bootclasspath>
                   </compilerArguments>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
        ....
       </plugins>
   </build>
```

Comment: It is fine to build against the Java 6 runtime library. That is not my problem.

Comment: Worked for me on a project .I didn't need the fork and compilerArguments target though for my project

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to set `-bootclasspath` as well so that `javac` compiles against JDK 1.5 bootstrap classes.

Try:

```
javac -source 1.6 -target 1.5 -bootclasspath /path/to/jdk1.5/lib/rt.jar -extdirs "" Foo.java
```

**UPDATE:**

Try removing the `-source` option, but keep the `-target` option.

I just tested it out:

```
# no source, only target => COMPILES to 1.5
$ javac -target 1.5 Foo.java
$ javap -v  Foo | grep version
  minor version: 0
  major version: 49

# no source, no target => COMPILES to 1.6
$ javac Foo.java
$ javap -v  Foo | grep version
  minor version: 0
  major version: 50

# both source and target => ERROR
$ javac -source 1.6 -target 1.5 Foo.java
javac: source release 1.6 requires target release 1.6

$ javac -version
javac 1.6.0_21
```

Comment: The problem is not that the classes are wrong, but that javac complain and do not start.

Comment: Your revised answer agrees with my own experiments.  Now, how do I make the maven compiler plugin do this, while still be compatible with the Maven plugin in Eclipse?

Comment: On jDK 7 this givers conflict error,
javac: target release 1.6 conflicts with default source release 1.7. Does not work

Answer (score 1):

What Java 6 language features are you using that are not present in Java 5? As far as I can tell, the only "feature" that's been added to the language is the use of the `@Override` annotation in `interface`s. Otherwise, Java 6 and Java 5 are source-compatible. What happens when you use:

```
<source>1.5</source>
<target>1.5</target>
```

in your Maven build file?

Comment: The `@Override` annotation requirement on interface implementations is exactly the desired feature here.

Comment: and here is more to that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335655/why-is-javac-failing-on-override-annotation

Comment: ... and also that the JAX-WS come with Java 6, and is an optional download in Java 5.  I want to have code which will run under a plain Java 6 but also can run under Java 5 with extra libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when I upgraded my IntelliJ IDE, it was fixed with the replacement of 1.5 with 1.6 as below.

```
       <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: The OP needs to maintain 1.6 java code (source = 1.6) while compiling it for java 1.5 (target) - in other words -- to make his 1.6 source run on 1.5 JRE. Your solution compiles for 1.6 JRE version

Comment: How would you do this with Java 9 ?

Answer (score -1):

The real question is thus to use `@Override` in source files that need to be compiled in Java 1.5 class files.

```
javac -source 1.5 -target 1.5 aFileWithOverride.java
```

will do just that. In jdk 7, this will lead to a warning

```
[options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.5
```

which is absent in jdk 6.

To get rid of this warning a special boot class jar can be created by adding the java 6 (or higher) `java.lang.annotation` package to a java 5 `rt.jar`.