# javac source and target options

Tags: java, javac

I have seen the compile options like discussed in [Which JDK's distributions can run `javac -source 1.6 -target 1.5`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260448/which-jdks-distributions-can-run-javac-source-1-6-target-1-5). I understand the individual options for source and target. I don't  understand why source version is higher that the target version. Compiling the code for older targets makes sense. But in that case, why dont we just use -source of the oldest target we want to be able to run on

Answer (score 44):

- source: The version that your source code requires to compile.
- target: The oldest JRE version you want to support.

Be sure to also set bootclasspath to ensure your program will work on older VMs.

---

From the `javac` [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#crosscomp-example):

> ### Cross-Compilation Example
>
> The following example uses javac to compile code that will run on a 1.6 VM.
>
> ```
> C\:>javac -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -bootclasspath C:\jdk1.6.0\lib\rt.jar -extdirs "" OldCode.java
> ```
>
> The `-source 1.6` option specifies that version 1.6 (or 6) of the Java programming language be used to compile `OldCode.java`. The option `-target 1.6` option ensures that the generated class files will be compatible with 1.6 VMs. Note that in most cases, the value of the `-target` option is the value of the `-source` option; in this example, you can omit the `-target` option.
>
> You must specify the `-bootclasspath` option to specify the correct version of the bootstrap classes (the `rt.jar` library). If not, the compiler generates the following warning:
>
> ```
> C:\>javac -source 1.6 OldCode.java
> warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
> ```
>
> If you do not specify the correct version of bootstrap classes, the compiler will use the old language rules (in this example, it will use version 1.6 of the Java programming language) combined with the new bootstrap classes, which can result in class files that do not work on the older platform (in this case, Java SE 6) because reference to non-existent methods can get included.

Answer (score 26):

Java is backwards compatible. You use the **-source** option to specify the java version used for compilation and you use the **-target** option to specify the lowest java version to support. eg. If I specify a target of 1.4, then my program will not be able to run on java 1.3 or lower. see the following javac [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) for more info. especially the section on **Cross-Compilation Options**

Comment: So then what's the point of having both? Why don't we just use the highest level source version, then have the target be something like 1.1? If java is backwards compatible, then what is the point of limiting the target versions?

Comment: To make use of the various improvements the implementations have to offer. Java 1.8 VM will have more features and improvements that Java 1.0 VM. The language is backwards compatible but not the equipment used to run it.

Comment: Would there be issues of compiling using a newer source version to run in an older target version? let's say I have some code using lambdas in Java 8...but my server runs Java 7. Would then  `-source 1.8 -target 1.7` be capable of allowing my code to run fine in Java 7?

Answer (score 4):

Peter Tseng does mention a lot of key points to remember during compilation. As a matter of fact even I faced a similar issue sometime back and want to share the root causes of many issues.

I had a source code which had to compiled & make it compatible (-source & -target) **Java '1.8'**. The code itself had

1. Lot of Trademark symbol hence I ended up in unrecognized characters(I had to tweak the IntelliJ Idea's encoding settings)
2. Lot of changes to `java.sql.*` package
3. Usage of lot of third-party libraries. Spare me the horror of explaining the difficulty debugging there and blah blah blah.

After certain changes I ended up with a code which had equal amount of JUnit test cases to run. Eventually I bumped into a `java.lang.VerifyError`. I was shocked when I understood that such error happens when I compile and run the code in the different libraries/environment(Which was not the case).

What I almost missed was that, for honoring the fact that the **tests had to run in an isolated environment, the Junit & its test cases where executed in a seperate forked VM**

```
<target name="runJunit">
    <junit printonsummary="on" 
           haltonfailure="off"
           fork="true"
           forkmode="once">
        <formatter />
        <batchtest />
        <classpath />
    </junit>
</target>
```

This obviously will be spanned as a separate process and act as a standalone application in execution. Even though the IDE spans both processes synchronously, the JVM's are pretty much isolated.

**After Java 1.7, Oracle has introduced a stricter verification and changed the class format a bit -- to contain a stack map, used to verify that code is correct**. The exception I had seen was because some method doesn't have a valid stack map. I eventually tried including lot of JVM options to tweak the setting, but in vain.

```
<jvmarg value="bootclasspath:{env.JAVA_HOME}\jre\bin\rt.jar" prefix="-X"/>
```

nothing worked. The only work around was to include

```
<jvmarg value=":UseSplitVerifier" prefix="-XX"/>
```

In Java 1.7 to allow only nominal byte code verification. Since this was taken off in Java 1.8, the only option was to use

```
<jvmarg value="-noverify"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

JDK1.8 will no longer support -source and -target less than 1.6

```
"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\javac.exe" -source 1.3 HelloWorld.java
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.3
warning: [options] source value 1.3 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 1.4 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
4 warnings
```