# Problems in running jar on Amazon ec2

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, jar, amazon-ec2

Hi I have a java project in eclipse. The main class as follows:

```
package aws;

public class Assignment3 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { }
}
```

My manifest file is:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: aws.Assignment3
```

I exported my executable jar with scp to my ec2 successfully. When I try to run my jar I get:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-138-8-38 project]$ java -jar alertShopper.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: aws/Assignment3 : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: aws.Assignment3. Program will exit.
```

I did

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-138-8-38 project]$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.1) (amazon-44.1.9.1.16.amzn1-i386)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 19.0-b06, mixed mode)
```

I don't know what else to do. Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks

I now got a new ec2 amazon ami and it has java 1.7 installed. But I need install jre-1.7 on amazon linux ami.

Comment: Upgrade to Java 7. Java 8 is nearly out, and Java 6 is ancient at this point.

Comment: i am trying sudo yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk on ec2 but says no package to install

Comment: That should work on the Amazon Linux AMI. Are you using a different one?

Comment: Its an amazon ec2 instance

Comment: You said that. You didn't say what AMI you're running.

Comment: If you mean the configurations of ec2 then the micro instance with Amazon Linux AMI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

This issue happens when java version used to compile your code is different than version you are running your code on. Higher version of JDK during compile time and lower version JDK during runtime.

You may need to [specify -target if you want to run lower version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492948/javac-source-and-target-options)

Comment: so should I recompile my project with different java version and make jar again?

Comment: @sa_nyc: Yes, you need to either upgrade runtime java version (or) use -target while compiling java code. Added reference in answer.

Comment: I tried to do sudo yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk on ec2 but it says no package to install

Comment: @sa_nyc: I don't know much about *nix. Best option may be use -target while compiling your code.

Comment: I need it to work via unix for amazon ec2

Answer (score 0):

All done did
`sudo yum install jre-1.7.0-openjdk` and changed to java 1.7.