# how to check java code compatibility with lower jre version

Tags: java, java-8

I wrote my java code (maven) using jdk-14.0.1. but I need to ensure that it would run on jre 1.8.
How can I check if my code is compatible with jre 1.8?

Comment: when compiling it, indicate the target to be java 8. If you use incompatible features, it will tell you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javac source and target options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492948/javac-source-and-target-options)

Comment: That’s precisely what the option `--release 8` is for

Comment: With JDK 9 release, a tool called **jdeprscan** (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jdeprscan.htm#JSWOR-GUID-2B7588B0-92DB-4A88-88D4-24D183660A62) has been introduced, which will verify the compatibility and list no longer used APIs within your code, suggest alternatives as well.

Comment: @njzk2 does this work for a maven project as well?