# Java Runtime Version

Tags: java, ubuntu, runtime

I just compiled a simple Java program in my Ubuntu Virtual Machine. It runned fine there.
When I copied the same ".class" file to Windows (host machine) I got the message below:

*"(...)has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 58.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0"*

Is there any way to fix this by implementing changes only my Ubuntu environment?

Answer (score 2):

Each version of the JDK has it's own class version.

A JDK can run files from a previous JDK but not from a future JDK.

58.0 is for JDK version 14.

52.0 is for JDK 8.

Either you can update the JDK on your windows machine

or

You can compile for a specific JDK using the -target command line option.

see

[List of Java class file format major version numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-class-file-format-major-version-numbers)

and

[javac source and target options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492948/javac-source-and-target-options)

Answer (score 0):

Java on your windows is Java8.
Java on Ubuntu is greater.

`java --version`

Gives you the numbers.

You can download a jdk and install it on Windows. Change the JAVA_HOME environment variable to use the new jdk.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  The OP specifically asked  *"Is there any way to fix this by implementing changes **only my Ubuntu environment**?"*