# Illegal reflective access in an applet with Jaxb and JDK 9

Tags: java, jaxb, applet, java-9, java-module

I have a Java applet which provides a GUI to invoke a web service. It uses Jaxb to parse the XML data and unmarshall it into objects. It runs correctly with Java 1.5 to 1.8. With Java 9, not so much.

I use a container HTML to launch it in Internet Explorer 8 + JDK 9:

```html
<applet code="com.blah.MyApplet" archive="myFatJarWithDependencies.jar" mayscript>
    <param name="cache_option" value="no" />
</applet>
```

The applet loads fine and seems to work; however, once I connect to the web service, it *kind of* stops working. **I have narrowed it down to this code fragment** (where *Foo* is an auto-generated class with XML bind annotations):

```java
System.out.println("1");
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);
System.out.println("2");
```

Java's console shows the `1`, and then... nothing: it doesn't crash, the applet is still responsive to mouse clicks, it doesn't throw any exceptions... there seems to be no error at all. Except for the fact that it doesn't do anything with the received data, and it never outputs the `2`. I've tried alternative `JAXBContext.newInstance` methods (with a package name, with a package name plus a class loader), but they all do the same.

If I run the project from Eclipse Oxygen with the same JDK 9, it *does* work. When I connect to the web service, it outputs a few warnings, including these:

```
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector 
(file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.0/jaxb-impl-2.0.jar) to method
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int)

WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access
operations
```

But then it goes on and loads the data (and outputs the `2` to the console). My guess is it's the same problem, even if the warnings are not shown in the Java console. <strike>Maybe the JDK defaults to `--illegal-access=deny` when it's being run from IE? Or *"silently-deny-so-the-user-dont-have-a-clue-on-whats-happening"*...</strike>

**Is there any way in which I can pass the `--illegal-access=permit` option to the JVM?** (Keep in mind that I'm not directly invoking the JVM, I only have an `<applet>` html tag)

**Is there any other way to make it work?** Perhaps add something extra in my applet's manifest file? (Which, by the way, looks like this):

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_144
Application-name: Blah
Permissions: all-permissions
Sealed: true

Name: blah/Blah.class
SHA-256-Digest: kpf244234234..ahjsdfksf=
...
```

These are the Jaxb dependencies I was using originally:

- javax.xml.bind : jaxb-api : 2.0
- com.sun.xml.bind : jaxb-impl : 2.0
- com.sun.xml.bind : jaxb-xjc : 2.0

I tried updating them from v2.0 to v2.3.0, which [are supposed to be compatible with Java 9](https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/doc/user-guide/release-documentation.html#a-2-3-0):

- javax.xml.bind : jaxb-api : 2.3.0
- com.sun.xml.bind : jaxb-impl : 2.3.0
- com.sun.xml.bind : jaxb-core : 2.3.0
- com.sun.xml.bind : jaxb-xjc : 2.3.0

But the problem still persists. Also tried these after [nullpointer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46474480/112934), with no luck either:

- javax.xml.bind : jaxb-api : 2.1
- javax.xml : jaxb-impl : 2.1
- removed the jaxb-xjc, apparently it's not needed...

Comment: I hope someone is able to help you resolve it, but I would suggest it is time to re-architect this particular front-end. Applets are largely dead these days.

Comment: Indeed, the applet api has also been deprecated in Java 9: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/289

Comment: Yes, I know... but that's not a decission I can make. And even if they approved the budget to change the applet into something else, it still would need to be embeded in a HTML page working in IE8. So...

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Even if applets are dead JAXB shouldn't be?

Answer (score 2):

**Maybe the JDK defaults to `--illegal-access=deny` when it's being run from IE?**

No, the current default mode of JDK is `permit` only.

> `--illegal-access=permit` opens each package in each module in the
>   run-time image to code in all *unnamed modules*, i.e., to code on the
>   class path, if that package existed in JDK 8. This enables both static
>   access, i.e., by compiled bytecode, and deep reflective access, via
>   the platform's various reflection APIs.
>
> The first reflective-access operation to any such package causes a
>   warning to be issued, but no warnings are issued after that point.
>   This single warning describes how to enable further warnings. This
>   warning cannot be suppressed.
>
> **This mode is the default in JDK 9**. It will be phased out in a future
>   release and, eventually, removed.

---

**Is there any other way to make it work?**

For using the `jaxb-api` would suggest you follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46220810/java-9-add-modules-only-on-compilation/46221811#46221811) to make sure that your module uses the `javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0` instead of `com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.0/jaxb-impl-2.0.jar` as seen in your logs.

You can configure the `maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0` as stated in the [documentation here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/module-info.html) to compile sources from 1.5 to JDK 8 in different execution and JDK in alternate execution.

Comment: I was already using javax's jaxb-api, the one from sun was jaxb-impl. Anyway I've replaced it too (updated the question with all the relevant dependencies), but it's still doing the same. What I don't get is... why does it behave differently in Eclipse vs IE8? It's the same JDK.

Comment: @AJPerez When you use it in eclipse what java version do you use? and in IE what is the default java version for you?

Comment: I'm running the applet with JDK 9 build 181, in both IE and Eclipse. And Eclipse itself is running with the same JDK. I'm using 1.8.0_144 to compile, but that shouldn't matter, right?

Comment: @AJPerez Ideally I would use the same version or higher(not a lower) to compile a code.Nor sure how do you compile the modular code uding jdk1,8 if that's what you meant.

Comment: I'm trying to compile with Java 9, and Maven 3.3 fails. I've found another question where you (it's a small world.. :) suggested [updating to Maven 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46500516/maven-throws-a-classnotfoundexception-codehaus-plexus-launcher-with-jdk-9), which I've just done. Now it tells me "source option 1.5 is no longer supported", so I either [tell Maven to use a compiler different than javac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970920/maven-javac-source-release-1-6-requires-target-release-1-6), or I give up with the whole Java 9 support...

Comment: @AJPerez The compiler plugin [configurations here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/module-info.html) shall help you compile -1.5. Updated in the answer as well.