# Crash Ropeytask with Java 9

Tags: java, spring-boot, groovy, jetty, java-9

RopeyTasks fail with the last update of java (9).

Source: https://github.com/continuumsecurity/RopeyTasks

And if I try to browser, I see:

```
HTTP ERROR: 503

Problem accessing /. Reason:

Service Unavailable
```

I can't understand where is the problem.

With java 8 Ropeytask works great and start correctly but seem that new version of Java 9 broke something of Spring framework/boot.
My question is if there is some workaround or compatibility mode for execute already deployed jar file (https://github.com/continuumsecurity/RopeyTasks/blob/master/ropeytasks.jar) without touch code or recompile.

The log is:

```
java -jar ropeytasks.jar
2017-10-08 00:41:03.489:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-7.x.y-SNAPSHOT
2017-10-08 00:41:04.699:INFO:oejpw.PlusConfiguration:No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
2017-10-08 00:41:04.717:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:NO JSP Support for , did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/private/var/folders/vc/6lpcq_l15z15zfbnjrppkshc0000gn/T/standalone-war/embedded10160800743692339444-exploded-1507416062907/WEB-INF/lib/groovy-all-2.4.10.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2017-10-08 00:41:05.510:INFO::Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2017-10-08 00:41:14,068 [main] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:733)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:233)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1214)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:676)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:455)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:90)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:261)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at grails.plugin.standalone.JettyLauncher.startJetty(JettyLauncher.java:122)
at grails.plugin.standalone.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:96)
at grails.plugin.standalone.JettyLauncher.main(JettyLauncher.java:58)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
... 12 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
... 12 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2248)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2214)
at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:276)
at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:110)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:415)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:377)
... 19 more
2017-10-08 00:41:14,071 [main] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener - Error initializing Grails: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:733)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:233)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1214)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:676)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:455)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:90)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:261)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at grails.plugin.standalone.JettyLauncher.startJetty(JettyLauncher.java:122)
at grails.plugin.standalone.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:96)
at grails.plugin.standalone.JettyLauncher.main(JettyLauncher.java:58)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
... 12 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
... 12 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2248)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2214)
at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:276)
at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:110)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:415)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:377)
... 19 more
2017-10-08 00:41:14.071:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{,file:/private/var/folders/vc/6lpcq_l15z15zfbnjrppkshc0000gn/T/standalone-war/embedded10160800743692339444-exploded-1507416062907/},/var/folders/vc/6lpcq_l15z15zfbnjrppkshc0000gn/T/standalone-war/embedded10160800743692339444-exploded-1507416062907
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:733)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:233)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1214)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:676)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:455)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:90)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:261)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at grails.plugin.standalone.JettyLauncher.startJetty(JettyLauncher.java:122)
at grails.plugin.standalone.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:96)
at grails.plugin.standalone.JettyLauncher.main(JettyLauncher.java:58)
Caused by:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:733)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:233)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1214)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:676)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:455)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:90)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:261)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at grails.plugin.standalone.JettyLauncher.startJetty(JettyLauncher.java:122)
at grails.plugin.standalone.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:96)
at grails.plugin.standalone.JettyLauncher.main(JettyLauncher.java:58)
Caused by:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:733)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:233)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1214)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:676)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:455)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:90)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:261)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at grails.plugin.standalone.JettyLauncher.startJetty(JettyLauncher.java:122)
at grails.plugin.standalone.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:96)
at grails.plugin.standalone.JettyLauncher.main(JettyLauncher.java:58)
Caused by:
org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:733)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:233)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1214)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:676)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:455)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:90)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:261)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at grails.plugin.standalone.JettyLauncher.startJetty(JettyLauncher.java:122)
at grails.plugin.standalone.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:96)
at grails.plugin.standalone.JettyLauncher.main(JettyLauncher.java:58)
Caused by:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2248)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2214)
at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:276)
at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:110)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:733)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:233)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1214)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:676)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:455)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:90)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:261)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at grails.plugin.standalone.JettyLauncher.startJetty(JettyLauncher.java:122)
at grails.plugin.standalone.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:96)
at grails.plugin.standalone.JettyLauncher.main(JettyLauncher.java:58)
Caused by:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:415)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:377)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2248)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2214)
at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:276)
at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:110)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:733)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:233)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1214)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:676)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:455)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:90)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:261)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at grails.plugin.standalone.JettyLauncher.startJetty(JettyLauncher.java:122)
at grails.plugin.standalone.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:96)
at grails.plugin.standalone.JettyLauncher.main(JettyLauncher.java:58)
2017-10-08 00:41:14.102:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@localhost:8080
Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to express dependency in maven on java ee features for transition to Java 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46084751/how-to-express-dependency-in-maven-on-java-ee-features-for-transition-to-java-9)..or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46474104/illegal-reflective-access-in-an-applet-with-jaxb-and-jdk-9/46474480#46474480

Comment: My question is also if is it possibile to execute a Jar file already compiled ... without touch code or recompile... maybe with a compatibility mode.. I tried illegal-access=permit but doesn't work

Comment: Did the `--add-modules` arg not work for you?

Comment: The --add-modules java.xml.bind works perfectly, thanks a lot. How can I mark your comment and the answer as solutions?

Comment: I would suggest closing this as a duplicate of linked question. Same solution has already been suggested on that link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in the [Modules Shared with Java EE Not Resolved by Default](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-F640FA9D-FB66-4D85-AD2B-D931174C09A3) section of the JDK 9 Migration Guide. You should find it works find once you put the JAXB API and implementation on the class path.