# @Override annotation thowing error in Eclipse Juno but not in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, eclipse, overriding, eclipse-indigo, eclipse-juno

I'm trying to move to using the latest version of Eclipse (Juno 4.2) but I am getting errors a project where I have used `@Override` annotation. The same project does not throw any errors in Eclipse Indigo.

I have had similar problems in the past but I have overcome them by changing the JRE on the buildpath. The settings for the project seems identical to me in Indigo and Juno. How do I solve this?

> [image]

...

> [image]

The compiler settings are also identical

> [image]

...

> [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect there are different "JDK compliance" settings for the two projects.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335655/why-is-javac-failing-on-override-annotation) which explains how @Override changed between Java 1.5 and 1.6.

Comment: They seem identical to me too. I've updated the question to show this.

Comment: Try altering the compliance level?

Comment: I toggled it back and forward between 1.6 and 1.7 and the errors disappeared. I'm sure I'd done the same from 1.5 to 1.6 previously and it had no effect. Thanks

Comment: After changing my git repository again I had the same issue when importing a maven project. Changing the compliance level and the compiler settings had no effect until I restarted Eclipse.

Comment: I'm wondering if the project settings file `(projectdir)/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` is checked into the Git repository?