# @Override not working in Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have several override methods like this:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Property p) {
    return getText().compareTo(p.getText());
}
```

As a Java project, it works fine, but as a Maven project, it returns the following error:

```
The method compareTo(Property) of type Property must override a superclass method
```

After researching into this, I think I'm suppose to include my JRE System Library (`jdk1.6_u25`) as a dependency in my POM file, or is this a completely different problem all together?

Many thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't need to add the JDK as a dependency. Can you confirm that your class is implementing `Comparable<Property>`?

Comment: Setting the JDK version like that won't work; if you want to set the source and target version, do so as explained under http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html However this is probably *not* the problem here.

Comment: @Will yes the class is implementing `Comparable<Property>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you all for your comments, a lot of you stated that Maven used Java 5 by default and could be the cause of the issue, and as a result, I was able to determine the problem through this answer:

[Why is javac failing on @Override annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335655/why-is-javac-failing-on-override-annotation)

The JDK compiler's compliance level was set to 1.5 by default; once I set it to 1.6, the errors were removed.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need another dependency. But by default, maven uses Java 5 language level, where `@Override` wasn't allowed for implementing interface methods. That was introduced in 6.

So you must configure the compiler plugin to use language level 6 like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                 <source>1.6</source>
                 <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply, I've copied and pasted your code and it returns `The managed version could not be determined. The managed definition location could not be determined, probably defined by "import" scoped dependencies.` Many thanks.

Comment: I've never sen that. Try adding `<version>3.1</version>` inside the `<plugin>` section.

Comment: It's OK I've found out what the problem was and posted it as an answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

`compareTo` is a generic method. Generics are not used so `compareTo(Object)` is the only method you can override.

Please check that:

1. Maven uses a java to compile that supports generics.
2. Source-Level is >= 5.

execute `mvn -V` to see what version of java maven uses to compile.

Regards

Comment: Apache Maven 3.2.1, Java version 1.6.0_25

Comment: @Kurtiss did you do 'mvn -V' via commandline like you `mvn install` via commandline or do you use a maven-eclipse-integration for any of them? Notice it might make a difference.

Comment: Got this info through the command prompt, anyways it's OK I've found out what the problem was and posted it as an answer. Thank you for your help.