# Getting improper compilation error for @Override annotation

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-luna

I have one interface **SysPropHelper**

```
package com.byteslounge.spring.tx.sys;

public interface SysPropHelper {

    void initSysProp();

}
```

and one class (**SysPropHelperImpl**) which implements this interface

```
package com.byteslounge.spring.tx.sys;

public class SysPropHelperImpl implements SysPropHelper {

    public void initSysProp() {

        System.out.println("From initSysProp method");
    }

}
```

Both are in the same package. From main method I just called the **initSysProp()** method and I got the desired result and the output is

> From initSysProp method

Still now everything is fine.

But when I annotated **initSysProp()** method of **SysPropHelperImpl** class with `@Override` annotation, surprisingly I got the below mentioned error

```
The method initSysProp() of type SysPropHelperImpl must override a superclass method
```

**Code after annotated initSysProp() method with @Override annoation**

```
package com.byteslounge.spring.tx.sys;

public class SysPropHelperImpl implements SysPropHelper {

    @Override
    public void initSysProp() {

        System.out.println("From initSysProp method");
    }

}
```

Trust me, I don't know why I am getting this error.I have restarted the Eclispe,restarted my machine, but no luck.

I am using **Eclipse Luna** and **JDK version is 1.7**.
If any one has any clue to fix this, please guide me.

The java compiler level and JRE are 1.7 in eclipse.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you are compiling your code for 1.7 version, not for 1.5? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335655/why-is-javac-failing-on-override-annotation

Comment: possible duplicate of ['Must Override a Superclass Method' Errors after importing a project into Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678122/must-override-a-superclass-method-errors-after-importing-a-project-into-eclips)

Comment: @ user3707125 yes. It's jdk1.7.0_40

Comment: With Oracle JDK 1.8.0_45, I cannot reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: @ Turing85 even in new workspace if I create the same thing, I am not getting any compilation error.

Comment: You've probably set the language level to 1.6.

Comment: @ beresfordt I don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: Though you are using a 1.7 SDK you must be targeting 1.5 bytecode; change the target to 1.6 or greater

Comment: *"even in new workspace if I create the same thing, I am not getting any compilation error."* So the error is gone?

Comment: @ beresfordt, I don't have any option to use other than 1.7. I am working  in client machine and I don't have access to install anything.

Comment: @  Turing85 in my workspace where I am working in project, it is still present.

Comment: I have not suggested you install anything. 'Though you are using a 1.7 SDK you must be targeting 1.5 bytecode; change the target to 1.6 or greater'

Comment: Just for documentation: I set my compilation level down to 1.7, 1.6 and 1.5. I was able to reproduce the behaviour on 1.5. So it is very likely that your compilation level (or compile target) is Java 1.5.

Comment: @ Turing85 but in my eclipse java compiler level and JRE all are set in 1.7.I have updated the question with all the settings.Even I can not reproduce the error in different workspace. Any other settings I need to check for this workspace?

Comment: You are using maven to build? Maybe (one of) the `pom.xml`(s) specifies 1.5 as target? Oh and by the way: please do not write a blank between the @ and people's names. We will not see your message in the inbox if you do that.

Comment: Yes I use maven, but in pom i did not mentioned any thing related to maven-compiler-plugin.

Comment: Probably Eclipse got messed up, restart it and rebuild (clean and rebuild).

Comment: @GoodBadandUgly First: if you use maven, your compiler settings in Eclipse do not matter at all. maven executes some compilation command independently from your Eclipse settings. Second: if you build your project, there should be some console output showing the actual compiler command (and I am pretty sure 1.5 is set as source). Please provide this. Third: go in your `pom.xml`, define 1.7 as your source. This should definitively fix the problem.

Comment: All the screen shots look OK, yet something in your workspace is telling Eclipse to compile for 1.5. A full zip file containing a minimal project for reproduction would be ideal for further analysis.