# when override interface function, error "method does not override method from its superclass"?

Tags: android, inheritance, overriding

Has an interface with some functions. The base class implements the interface. Then in the subclass would like to override the function.

But the @override gives complier error "method does not override method from its superclass"

Question: in sub class, how to override the interface function implemented in base class?

```
public interface TheCallback {
    void onImageUrlReady(final ImageView view, final ImageRecord imageData);
```

}

```
public class ImageFragment extends Fragment implements TheCallback {

    @Override 
    void onImageUrlReady(final ImageView view, final ImageRecord imageData) {
        //base class implementation
    }
}

public class DerivedFragment extends ImageFragment  {
    @Override //<=== got compile error here
    void onImageUrlReady(final ImageView view, final ImageRecord imageData) {
        //sub class override implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing the `e` in `@Override` in both places.

Comment: sorry, that is a typo. in the code it is indeed @Override. Just edited the question to correct the typo. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using Java 1.5. @Override can be used on implemented interface methods from 1.6.

Also see [Why is javac failing on @Override annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335655/why-is-javac-failing-on-override-annotation)