# Andengine GLES2 - IS the repository copy broken?

Tags: android, andengine

I've just grabbed the tip of Andengine GLES2 from github. When I bring the project in to Eclipse, its got LOTS of problems. 
But the main problem is that there are many places in which  @override is used on objects which have no superclass.

Is it just me? Is there working version of GLES2?

Comment: @Charles - Andengine GLES1 and GLES2 are incompatible, use different packages, and a different API. IMHO that justifies a separate tag, because a solution for one, will not work on the other. To illustrate the point, android encompases andengine, and java encompasses android. Yet each has its own tag, for obvious reasons. I'm hoping that introducing a new tag for GLES2 will add utility for end users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the anmswer to my own question: in java 1.6 overrides can be in place for implemented methods. Description of trouble here:

[Eclipse ignoring incorrect @Override annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407198/eclipse-ignoring-incorrect-override-annotations)